# Encounter CORS Policy from Reactjs to Laravel 8 api

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, laravel-8, laravel-api

I have API using laravel 8. This API was made each Module. Laravel API running in localhost port 8000. Then i have reactjs app running in localhost port 3000. If i access api by URL or Rest Client extension VSCode it work. I tried get data using axios from react js and it work too. But when i tried post data from reactjs to api laravel, it encounter CORS Policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested. Post request API i've tried in Rest Client extension and it work. Please help me whats wrong with it. Here my code:

Laravel API Route

```
Route::prefix('esi')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/survey/store', 'SurveyController@store');
});
```

Laravel Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $insert = Survey::insert([
               'name' => $request->input('name'),
               'date' => $request->input('date'),
               'answer' => $request->input('answer'),
           ]);

        if($insert){
           return response()->json(['msg' => 'Success'], 201);
        } else {
           return response()->json(['msg' => 'Failed'], 500);
        }
    }
```

React JS handleSubmit

```
formData = new formData();
formData.append('name', name);
formData.append('date', date);
formData.append('answer', answer);

try {
   const response = await axios.post(
       "http://localhost:8000/api/esi/survey/store",
       formData
   );
   console.log(response);
} catch(e) {
   console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: if it is Laravel 8 I believe the CORS package should already be included check if your `HTTP/Kernel.php` also `cors.php` to see if you have modified anything

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, issues like this are usually caused by little mistakes, you will need to know which part is causing the problem, whether it is front-end or backend-end, to achieve this, download any HTTP client software.

Postman is a good choice [Download Postman Here](https://www.postman.com/downloads), then test your endpoint "http://localhost:8000/api/esi/survey/store" with sample data to see if the problem is with Laravel or Reactjs, if the problem persists, then you need to look at your CORS configuration which you can find at this location in your Laravel app "config/cors.php", check if you have modified any line, I have added a default CORS configuration below

```
<?PHP
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

I hope this helps you